# Merging multiple VPC's

Tags: amazon-web-services, router, amazon-vpc

I'm trying to merge multiple VPC's with site-to-site OpenVPN. I think it is almost successful but I face a strange behaviour.

Here are the setting:

- VPC 1: 10.20.0.0/16

  - WebServer1: 10.20.49.147 (inside 10.20.48.0/20 subnet)
  - NATInstance1: 10.20.29.239 (inside 10.20.16.0/20 subnet)
- VPC 2: 10.250.0.0/16

  - WebServer2: 10.250.55.41 (inside 10.250.48.0/20 subnet)
  - NATInstance2: 10.250.250.98 (inside 10.250.224.0/20 subnet)

VPC 1 and VPC 2 is on the different region(In fact, I'm trying to connect 4 VPC's on each different regions)

I setup the NATInstance2 as a OpenVPN server and the NATInstance1 as a OpenVPN client(via 192.168.x.x virtual IP), and it worked well. However, I also want to make this environment work as if whole big 10.0.0.0/8 network, so WebServer1 will have to be able to connect WebServer2, vice versa.

Strangely, NATInstance1 can connect to WebServer2 via SSH, but the reverse is not. NATInstance2 also can connect to WebServer1 via SSH, but the reverse is not. Of course, the connection between WebServer1 and WebServer2 is not possible, either.

Since I want to make those all connections possible, what should I have to change in setting?

---

FYI, The routing table settings for NATInstances are:

NATInstance1:
`root@openvpn ~# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.20.16.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.20.16.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
10.250.0.0      192.168.0.13    255.255.0.0     UG    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.0.1     192.168.0.13    255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun0
192.168.0.13    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0`

NATInstance2:
`root@openvpn ~# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.250.240.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.20.0.0       192.168.0.2     255.255.0.0     UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.250.240.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     192.168.0.2     255.255.0.0     UG    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.0.2     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0`

The routing tables in AWS VPC setting are:

- The subnet(10.20.48.0/20) for WebServer1:

  - 10.20.0.0/16: local
  - 0.0.0.0/0: NATInstance1
- The subnet(10.20.16.0/20) for NATInstance1:

  - 10.20.0.0/16: local
  - 0.0.0.0/0: IGW
  - 10.0.0.0/8: NATInstance1

And the VPC 2 subnets are similarly set.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved this problem by disabling IP check in EC2 OpenVPN instance.

Answer (score 0):

The use of OpenVPN is a requirement for your environment? if not you can try the [VPC Peering](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-peering.html).

A VPC peering connection is a networking connection between two VPCs that enables you to route traffic between them using private IP addresses. Instances in either VPC can communicate with each other as if they are within the same network. You can create a VPC peering connection between your own VPCs, or with a VPC in another AWS account within a single region.

AWS uses the existing infrastructure of a VPC to create a VPC peering connection; it is neither a gateway nor a VPN connection, and does not rely on a separate piece of physical hardware. There is no single point of failure for communication or a bandwidth bottleneck.

Comment: It was actually impossible to try VPC Peering because the VPC's were in different regions.